# Syntax for no_proxy in .gitconfig

Tags: git, proxy

I'm trying to find a working .gitconfig setup that fulfills two requirements:

- sslVerify must be set to false for internal servers or at least for one specific server
- a proxy needs to be configured for external repositories (with sslVerify set to true, of course).

My current version gives me access problems when connecting to my internal repo. I guess that somehow that two last instructions are wrong.

```
[user]
    name = John Doe
    email = john.doe@company.com
[https]
    proxy = http://johndoe:password@1.2.3.4:6666
[http]
    proxy = http://johndoe:password@1.2.3.4:6666
[http "https://repo.company.com/"]
    sslVerify = false
[https "https://repo.company.com/"]
    sslVerify = false
```

What is the correct syntax for this case? I use Git 2.12.2.windows.2.

Answer (score 1):

You must add the proxy field in the config, however the address(field) can be left blank.

Below is a sample config file:

```
[user]
    name = user
    email = user@company.com
[http]
    sslVerify = true
    proxy = http://user:password@proxy:8080
[https]
    sslVerify = true
    proxy = http://user:password@proxy:8080
[http "https://git.company.com/"]
    sslVerify = false
    proxy = 
[https "https://git.company.com/"]
    sslVerify = false
    proxy = 
[url "git@somegit.company.com:"]
    insteadOf = https://somegit.company.com
```

Answer (score 0):

you must add the proxy address in your .gitconfig file for your specific :

```
[http "https://repo.company.com/"]
    sslVerify = false
    proxy = http://johndoe:password@1.2.3.4:6666
```